# batch file send mail after task done

Tags: email, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to send e-mail via PowerShell after my batchfile complete.
My batch file is:

```
@echo on

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set folderpath= "mypath"

@echo on

cd %folderpath%

for /f %%a in ('dir /b "%folderpath%\*.txt"') do (
   set "fname=%%~na"
   ren "%%a" "!fname:~0,-33!.txt"
)

%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe C:\myfolder\my_powershell_script.ps1

pause
```

My PowerShell script is:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope LocalMachine Unrestricted

$smtpServer = "my server"

$msg = New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)

$msg.From = ("mail from")
$msg.To.Add("mail to")
$msg.Subject = "subject"
$msg.Body = "body"

$smtp.Send($msg)
```

I'm getting an error message:

> exception calling send with 1 argument(s) failure sending mail

any help?

Comment: Try changing your `msg.from` and `msg.to.add()`to valid mail addresses. Is your mailserver accepting mails if not authenticated?

Comment: in my code there is a valid mailboxes which i dont want to be public,
and yes, my mail server accept not authenticate mails

Comment: Does it work, if you are just running the mail part inside ise?

Comment: it's work when i run it on my local computer but when i try to run it from the server it doesn't

Comment: Are you using same credentials? Can the server reach the mailserver on port 25? Basically that sounds, like the problem is not in your script.

Comment: i think it's firewall issue...what do you suggest?

Comment: Either you need to add the servers ip on the receive connector (if your mailserver is Exchange) or you need to check that Firewall.

Comment: Either way it's a question for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), not for SO.